# Assembly NASM x86 - Putting char into array

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, nasm

I need to make a program that  open a file, read it character by character and save it into an array in Assembly NASM x86. Currently, the program is able to open a file using stdin and read the character by using getchar(). However, i am stuck on the saving the char into an array and need help on this part.

Thank you

```
; Run it this way:
; test < (input file)
; Build using these commands:
; nasm -f elf -g -F stabs test.asm
; gcc –m32 -o test.o  test
;

SECTION .bss ; Section containing uninitialized data

    TextLenght EQU 1024 ; Define length of a line of  text data
    Text resb TextLenght ; Define array

SECTION .data ; Section containing initialised data

fileFmt: db "%c",0

SECTION .text ; Section containing code

extern putchar 
extern getchar
extern printf

global main; Linker needs this to find the entry point!

main :

start:
    nop ; This no-op keeps gdb happy...
    mov eax, 0
    mov edx, 0
    mov ecx, 0
    mov ebx, 0

; Read a buffer full of text from stdin:
read:
    call getchar ; call getchar to get input from stdin, char is save in eax 
    cmp al, -1
    jle Done     ; if return -1, we at EOF

    cmp eax, 97  ; get rid of 'enter' char
    jl read

    ;mov Text, eax; try to save char in eax into array, don;t work

    push eax      ;push eax to print  
    push fileFmt
    call printf
    add esp, 8   ; clear the stack
    jmp read

Done:
    mov eax,1 ; Code for Exit Syscall
    mov ebx,0 ; Return a code of zero
    int 80H ; Make sys_exit kernel call
```

Comment: Well, did you try `mov [Text], al` ?

Comment: To check for EOF/error from `getchar()`, check all of `eax`.  Otherwise you can't tell the difference between EOF and reading a `0xFF` byte, e.g. as part of a UTF-8 string.  This is why [the function signature has an `int` return value](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html), not `char`.

Comment: Also, zeroing eax,ecx, and edx before calling `getchar` is useless.  You have to assume that every function call to a function you didn't write yourself modifies those registers.  You use an `exit` system call instead of returning, so it's ok that you clobber the caller's `ebx`.

Comment: @Michael: So i made the changes suggested above and the code compile now, but how do i print out the content in Text. I try to replace 'push eax' with 'push Text',  but it doesn't print out  anything.